# To receive rotation from a matrix

Tags: javascript, matrix

How to receive turn degree from a matrix?
for example:
 there is a matrix [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1].
 It is rotated on a x axis on 90 degrees.
 How from a matrix to receive these most 90 degrees?
javascript code:

```
var a=[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1];
function rotateX(m, angle)
{
    var c = Math.cos(angle);
    var s = Math.sin(angle);
    var mv1 = m[1], mv5 = m[5], mv9 = m[9];
    m[1] = m[1] * c - m[2] * s;
    m[5] = m[5] * c - m[6] * s;
    m[9] = m[9] * c - m[10] * s;
    m[2] = m[2] * c + mv1 * s;
    m[6] = m[6] * c + mv5 * s;
    m[10] = m[10] * c + mv9 * s;
}
rotateX(a,90);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: How does `[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1]` map to a matrix?

Answer (score 0):

If `m[1]` and `m[2]` model a point, then you're broadly correct.

The only problem you have is that you're assuming that `Math.cos` and `Math.sin` accept an angle in *degrees*. They don't: you need to supply units in *radians*.

To convert an angle from degrees to radians, multiply by Pi then divide by 180. Supply that value to the trigonometric functions.